# Cron is trying (and failing) to open env file: /etc/environment

Tags: debian, cron, environment-variables, pam, devuan

I'm using Devuan ASCII (which is more or less Debian 9, Stretch). Now, my `/var/log/auth.log` has a bunch of these entries:

```
Jan  6 09:45:01 mybox CRON[20951]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/environment: No such file or directory
Jan  6 09:45:01 mybox CRON[20951]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

which apparently get generated when I `su`.

1. Why is cron/pam_env/pam_unix trying to open that file in the first place, rather than checking whether it exists?
2. If they legitimately expect it, why isn't it there?
3. What should I do about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering all of your questions

> 1. Why is cron/pam_env/pam_unix trying to open that file in the first place?

[See BUG #646015](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=646015). In some cases (like locale related stuff) this file is deprecated. But it is still used system-wide, and log is made whenever it is missing.

> 2. If they legitimately expect it, why isn't it there?

Cause maybe the bug isn't fixed after all. Steve Langasek  ([BUG #646015](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=646015)) said it is, and new systems should create that file using `postinst` scripts the same way old systems being upgraded should already have that file.

> 3. What should I do about this?

- Run `dpkg-reconfigure libpam-modules` and see if it will create the file through its `postinst` script.
- If that does not work, create the file manually with `touch /etc/environment`

It's also interesting to report your issue to the Devuan Project with details of the problem and your setup since this issue was resolved before the Debian/Devuan fork happened.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure` will not help, and nor will `apt install --reinstall`, because the file is only created on fresh install or upgrades from a *very* old version of `libpam-modules`. There is an alternative method, but considering how easy it is to create the file manually, and how critical PAM is to the working of the system, I think you may as well use the manual approach.

Comment: I got the error on a Debian system. `/etc` is tracked by etckeeper, but unfortunately I don't have any record of the file. OTOH a clean `debootstrap --variant=minbase stretch` does create `etc/environment`.  So, I wonder if there is or was a problem with the installer somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

An inelegant but perfectly valid solution is to give those modules what they want: As root, execute

```
touch /etc/environment
```

and to make sure the permissions are right, just in case:

```
chmod 644 /etc/environment
```

Comment: Note that this behavior is completely normal. The `pam_env` is expected to look for `/etc/environment` and that's [the default](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) way that the `/etc/environment` file is read, at least on Linux systems.

Comment: I have it here: `cat /etc/environment` 
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct

Comment: @terdon: Looking for it is fine, assuming it exists is not fine. It's either a bug in `pam_env` or an issue with Debian.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug of the specific distro. That is a standard file and it exists in Debian. But is this actually a problem? Does it cause any issue other than a message in the log?